# Calling a function out of several other functions?

Tags: python

So I have several functions written and I want to call one of them for use, my input code I used at the bottom asks for the function name but doesn't do much of anything with it. I'm a newbie so I might have missed something here, thanks.

```
    def summ(num1 = 0, num2 = 0):
        num1 = int(input('första num: '))
        num2 = int(input('andra num: '))
        total = num1 + num2
        print(total)
        return num1 + num2


    def kvad(num = 0):
        num = int(input('kvadrerat nummer..'))
        power = num**2
        print(power)
        return power


    def udda(udd = 0):
        udd = int(input('jämnt eller udda?'))
        if udd % 2 != 0:
                print('Udda..')
        elif udd % 2:
            print('jämnt')
        return udda



    import operator
    def kalkylera(num1 = 0, num2 = 0):

        num1 = int(input('first num'))
        num2 = int(input('second num'))
        #operators
        subb = operator.sub(num1, num2)
        addd = operator.add(num1,num2)
        mull = operator.mul(num1,num2)
        divv = operator.truediv(num1,num2)

        oper8 = input('Vilket operation ska tillämpas?')
        if oper8 == '-':
            print(subb)
        elif oper8 == '+':
            print(addd)
        elif oper8 == '*':
            print(mull)
        elif oper8 == '/':
            print(divv)

call = input('vilket funktion?')

if call == summ:
    summ()
elif call == kvad:
    kvad()
elif call == udda:
    udda()
elif call == kalkylera:
    kalkylera()
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: `if call == "value":`

Comment: In your code **replace** `if call  == func_name:` with `if call == "func_name":` where `func_name` is the **name of function** you want to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
functions = {
    "summ": summ,
    "kvad": kvad,
    "udda": udda,
    "kalkylera": kalkylera,
}
call = input('vilket funktion?')

function = functions.get(call)
if function is None:
    raise RuntimeError('Unknown function to call')
function()
```

This is a more explicit approach. It also allows you to specify a different code name for each function.

Alternatively you could use:

```
function = globals().get(call)
```

But this smells. Explicit is better than implicit (Zen of Python).

Answer (score 0):

- below code should work as per your requirement
- you need to use single or double quotes otherwise it will treat as variable

```
import operator


def summ(num1=0, num2=0):
    num1 = int(input('första num: '))
    num2 = int(input('andra num: '))
    total = num1 + num2
    print(total)
    return num1 + num2


def kvad(num=0):
    num = int(input('kvadrerat nummer..'))
    power = num**2
    print(power)
    return power


def udda(udd=0):
    udd = int(input('jämnt eller udda?'))
    if udd % 2 != 0:
        print('Udda..')
    elif udd % 2:
        print('jämnt')
    return udda


def kalkylera(num1=0, num2=0):

    num1 = int(input('first num'))
    num2 = int(input('second num'))
    # operators
    subb = operator.sub(num1, num2)
    addd = operator.add(num1, num2)
    mull = operator.mul(num1, num2)
    divv = operator.truediv(num1, num2)

    oper8 = input('Vilket operation ska tillämpas?')
    if oper8 == '-':
        print(subb)
    elif oper8 == '+':
        print(addd)
    elif oper8 == '*':
        print(mull)
    elif oper8 == '/':
        print(divv)


call = input('vilket funktion?')
if call == "summ":
    summ()
elif call == "kvad":
    kvad()
elif call == "udda":
    udda()
elif call == "kalkylera":
    kalkylera()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in that you should wrap the `summ` and `kvad` and other methods with double quotation marks.

```
call = input('vilket funktion?')

if call == "summ":
    summ()
elif call == "kvad":
    kvad()
elif call == "udda":
    udda()
elif call == "kalkylera":
    kalkylera()
```

But it's a better solution to do that via `eval`:

```
eval(f"{input()}()")
```